# Real and imaginary part of an analytic function are harmonic?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, analytic-functions

Let $f:\Bbb{C}\to\Bbb{C}$ be an analytic function. For $z = x+iy,$ let $u,v : \mathbb{R}^2  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 $ be such that
$u(x,y) = \operatorname{Re}f(z)$ and $v(x,y) = \operatorname{Im}f(z)$.
Then which of the following are correct,

1.$\dfrac{\partial ^2u}{\partial x^2} + \dfrac{\partial ^2u}{\partial y^2} = 0$

2.$\dfrac{\partial ^2v}{\partial x^2} + \dfrac{\partial ^2v}{\partial y^2} = 0$

3.$\dfrac{\partial ^2u}{\partial x \partial y} - \dfrac{\partial ^2u}{\partial y \partial x} = 0$

*My try:* Since $\operatorname{Re} f(z)$ and $\operatorname{Im}f(z)$ parts of an analytic function satisfies Cauchy Riemann Equation. We can conclude all the options holds.

But it's displayed option $2$ is incorrect. Is that so?

Comment: No, option $2$ is correct. Since $\Delta f=0$ for analytic $f$ by CR equations, note that $\Delta f = 0 + 0i$ so that the real and imaginary parts must both be $0$.

Answer (score 3):

If $f = u + iv$ then $f' = u_x + i v_x = {1 \over i} (u_y+i v_y)$ and hence
$f'' = u_{xx} + i v_{xx} = -(u_{yy} + i v_{yy})$. Then 1 & 2 follow from this.

Similarly, $f'' = {1 \over i} (u_{xy}+ i v_{xy}) = {1 \over i} (u_{yx}+ i v_{yx}) $ and 3 follows from this.

Comment: How can we state ''hence $f''=u_{xx}+iv_{xx}=...$'' unless establishing $f$ (and thereby $u$ and $v$) are twice differentiable?

Comment: @Riaz $f$ is analytic, hence smooth.

Comment: I hope the nicety of $f$ is due to Taylor's theorem, right?

Comment: @Riaz It is more than Taylor's theorem.

Comment: I would appreciate if you suggest some references for the proof, thanks in advance.

Comment: @Riaz I am not sure which proof you are referring to, it is a standard result in Complex analysis. Conway (Functions of one complex variable) defines analytic as continuously differentiable (Definition 2.3), shows that an analytic function is smooth (Corollary 2.12) and later Goursat's Theorem shows that a differentiable function defined on an open set is analytic.