# Prove that function satisfy differential equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f(x)$ is bounded on $\mathbb{R}$ and integrable on any finite segment.
So, how to prove that for any $x > 0$ the function $$u(x, y) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{xf(z)}{x^2 + (y - z)^2}\,dz$$ satisfy the following differential equation : $$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}  = 0.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing the derivatives inside the integral (with the Dominated Convergence Theorem, for example) requires us to compute
$$ \left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}\right) \frac{x}{x^2+(y-z)^2}. $$
But the function to be differentiated is the real part of
$$ \frac{x-i(y-z)}{x^2+(y-z)^2} = \frac{1}{(x+iy)-iz}, $$
which is analytic in the right half-plane $x>0$, so by the Cauchy–Riemann equations, its real part satisfies Laplace's equation.

Comment: [+1] One should add that it is a very classical result (see (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1806071)) about **harmonic** functions (a keyword that can be useful for subsequent searches).